# How to make smooth expansion animation with icon appearance in css?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, css-transitions

I have this piece of code which consists of a featured blog post section on my website. I made an icon to appear when hovering the `.read-further`, however it doesn't really do a smooth transition animation using CSS. Is there a way to fix this? Or is JavaScript needed here? Here's the complete code:

```css
.read-further {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0.50%;
  padding: 0.50%;
  width: fit-content;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ece5e0;
  background-color: #363945;
  border-radius: 44px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.read-further:hover {
  width: auto;
  background-color: #bb4b42;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.5);
}

.read-further a {
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  color: #ece5e0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.read-further i {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #ece5e0;
  font-size: larger;
  left: 1.75%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.read-further:hover>i {
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  -webkit-animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
  animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="container">
  <section class="container-child">
    <a id="cc-tag" href="">Tech</a>
    <a href=""><img src="/img/example-image.png" alt="example"></a>
    <h3>Example Article</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error harum magni voluptate facilis, blanditiis quisquam</p>
    <div class="read-further">
      <a href="">Read more...</a>
      <i href="" class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/exg24pqw/

Thanks in advance.

I tried "transition" property in various ways but it didn't do the work.

Comment: I think everyone did get used to use AI they do not even look here anymore :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason your `transition: all .25s ease-out` isn't working is because of `fit-content` and `auto` width, you can give an static width for your button when it's not hovered. the `auto` width makes the button to full-fit its parent width so you can use `width:100%;` instead.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.read-further {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0.50%;
  padding: 0.50%;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ece5e0;
  background-color: #363945;
  border-radius: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* z-index: 1; *//*z-index works when the element has a position*/
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.read-further:hover {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bb4b42;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.5);
}

.read-further a {
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  color: #ece5e0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.read-further i {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #ece5e0;
  font-size: larger;
  left: 1.75%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.read-further:hover>i {
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  -webkit-animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
  animation: scale-up-hor-left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.4);
    transform: scaleX(0.4);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="container">
  <section class="container-child">
    <a id="cc-tag" href="">Tech</a>
    <a href=""><img src="/img/example-image.png" alt="example"></a>
    <h3>Example Article</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error harum magni     voluptate facilis, blanditiis quisquam</p>
    <div class="read-further">
      <a href="">Read more...</a>
      <i href="" class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

i hope this solves your problem!